How to optimize three almost-the-same functions into one?
so basically i have this:
let quizCheck1Option = document.querySelectorAll ('.js-quiz_step2check1_option-popup');
let quizCheck1Img = document.querySelectorAll ('.js-quiz_step2check1_img');
let quizCheck1Title = document.querySelectorAll ('.js-quiz_step2check1_title');
    quizCheck1Option.forEach(label => {
        label.addEventListener('click', function() {
            quizCheck1Img.forEach(img => {
                img.setAttribute ("src", label.dataset.src);
                document.getElementById('quiz2-option-1').checked=true;
            })
            quizCheck1Title.forEach(title => {
                title.innerText = label.dataset.name;
            })
        })
    })

let quizCheck2Option = document.querySelectorAll ('.js-quiz_step2check2_option-popup');
let quizCheck2Img = document.querySelectorAll ('.js-quiz_step2check2_img');
let quizCheck2Title = document.querySelectorAll ('.js-quiz_step2check2_title');
    quizCheck2Option.forEach(label => {
        label.addEventListener('click', function() {
            quizCheck2Img.forEach(img => {
                img.setAttribute ("src", label.dataset.src);
                document.getElementById('quiz2-option-2').checked=true;
            })
            quizCheck2Title.forEach(title => {
                title.innerText = label.dataset.name;
            })
        })
    })

let quizCheck3Option = document.querySelectorAll ('.js-quiz_step2check3_option-popup');
let quizCheck3Img = document.querySelectorAll ('.js-quiz_step2check3_img');
let quizCheck3Title = document.querySelectorAll ('.js-quiz_step2check3_title');
    quizCheck3Option.forEach(label => {
        label.addEventListener('click', function() {
            quizCheck3Img.forEach(img => {
                img.setAttribute ("src", label.dataset.src);
                document.getElementById('quiz2-option-3').checked=true;
            })
            quizCheck3Title.forEach(title => {
                title.innerText = label.dataset.name;
            })
        })
    })

These three blocks of code are the same except 1-2-3 numbers (quizCheck1-, quizCheck2-, quizCheck3-). I am sure there is a way to optimize this.
I'm a newbie at JS so any other suggestions to improve the code would be appreciated!
I am sure there is a way to make these three blocks into one but with swithing those 1-2-3 numbers with something like i++ thingy...

Can you provide the HTML that you reference in this script? A good solution will also revise the CSS class names you have thought of (removing the numbering inside them) and take benefit of the hierarchical structure you will have in your HTML.

Create a function that takes the necessary parameters and performs the required actions and use the function to handle each set of elements by passing the appropriate arguments. You can learn more about functions and parameters in JS.

Just create a function and pass the option index as a parameter, like
function yourFunction(optionIndex) {
    let quizCheckOption = document.querySelectorAll ('.js-quiz_step2check'+optionIndex+'_option-popup');
    let quizCheckImg = document.querySelectorAll ('.js-quiz_step2check'+optionIndex+'_img');
    let quizCheckTitle = document.querySelectorAll ('.js-quiz_step2check'+optionIndex+'_title');
    quizCheckOption.forEach(label => {
        label.addEventListener('click', function() {
            quizCheckImg.forEach(img => {
                img.setAttribute ("src", label.dataset.src);
                document.getElementById('quiz2-option-'+optionIndex).checked=true;
            })
            quizCheck3Title.forEach(title => {
                title.innerText = label.dataset.name;
            })
        })
    })
}

then you can call it 3 times, or as many as you need (yourFunction(2))
